# mono: DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact works on full .NET but not on debian

Tags: c#, mono, datetimeoffset

My C# project is taking xml and extracting pertinent data, one of which pieces is a date time value. The following code works correctly on my desktop running Win8.1 and .NET4. However when I run it through mono, it's failing to parse the data.

```
using glob = System.Globalization;

DateTimeOffset dt = DateTimeOffset.MinDate;
string[] fmts = new string[]
{
    "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt EDT",
    "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt EST",
    "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt CDT",
    "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt CST",
    "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt MDT",
    "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt MST",
    "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt AKST",
    "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt AKDT",
    "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt HST",
    "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt PST",
    "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt PDT"
};
var dtString = z.Substring(pos1 + 5, pos2 - pos1 - 1 - 5).Replace("ft", "").Trim();
dtString = dtString.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + dtString.Substring(1);
dtString = dtString.Substring(0, dtString.Length - 7)
    + dtString.Substring(dtString.Length - 7).ToUpper();

DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(dtString, fmts,
    glob.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, glob.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

To check if the conversion worked ok, I do this:

```
   if (dt == DateTimeOffset.MinDate)
       Console.WriteLine("failed to convert dt = MinValue -> " + dtString);
```

Here's an example of the data string being processed:

```
raw: mar 21, 2015 10:30 am cdt
after my formatting: Mar 21, 2015 10:15 AM CDT
```

It's not specific to the CDT tz - I get the same issue for all timezones.

When I run $ date on the Linux box, it's reporting the same date, time and tz as my desktop, in this format (Mon Mar 23 11:31:16 EDT 2015).

The section is wrapped in a try/catch, but no exceptions are being thrown (also have Console output in there).

I can code around it by changing the string around before TryParse, but it would seem this method was designed so that this is not necessary.

Is this a bug (or am I missing something)? If so where does one report them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- In the code you posted, the part where you manipulate the `dtString` variable is meaningless to us, because you didn't include values for `pos1` or `pos2`.  It seems quite messy, and in general - that sort of manipulation should be avoided if possible.  I'm not sure what it has to do with your question, if anything.
- You are using the `TryParseExact` method, which returns a boolean `true` on success - so the comparison check is unnecessary.  (Also, the field is called `MinValue`, not `MinDate`)
- Time zone abbreviations are not valid in format strings.  The letters in the string could be confused with actual [custom formatting values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).  If you wanted to exclude them, you would place them in single-tick or double-tick quotation marks.
- In general, time zone abbreviations should not be used for input.  There are just too many ambiguities.  For example, [this list of abbreviations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) shows 5 possible interpretations of `"CST"`.
- The parsers that come with the `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` types do not understand time zone abbreviations at all.  You claim it works fine on your desktop under .NET 4, but I call BS.

  [image: Code]
  [image: Output]

  As you can see, it did not interpret the offset as CDT (-05:00).  Instead it took the local time zone from my computer, which happens to be PDT (-07:00).

The correct way to deal with this is to parse the date input as a `DateTime`, then use some other mechanism to determine the offset.  If you *MUST* use the time zone abbreviation, and you are absolutely sure you only have the time zones you showed above, and they're all from the united states, then it would go something like this:

```
// define the list that you care about
private static readonly Dictionary<string, TimeSpan> Abbreviations = new Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>
{
    {"EDT", TimeSpan.FromHours(-4)},
    {"EST", TimeSpan.FromHours(-5)},
    {"CDT", TimeSpan.FromHours(-5)},
    {"CST", TimeSpan.FromHours(-6)},
    {"MDT", TimeSpan.FromHours(-6)},
    {"MST", TimeSpan.FromHours(-7)},
    {"PDT", TimeSpan.FromHours(-7)},
    {"PST", TimeSpan.FromHours(-8)},
    {"AKDT", TimeSpan.FromHours(-8)},
    {"AKST", TimeSpan.FromHours(-9)},
    {"HST", TimeSpan.FromHours(-10)}
};

static DateTimeOffset ParseInput(string input)
{
    // get just the datetime part, without the abbreviation
    string dateTimePart = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf(" ", StringComparison.Ordinal));

    // parse it to a datetime
    DateTime dt;
    bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimePart, "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);

    // handle bad input
    if (!success)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid input string.", "input");
    }

    // get the abbreviation from the input string
    string abbreviation = input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf(" ", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1)
                                .ToUpperInvariant();

    // look up the offset from the abbreviation
    TimeSpan offset;
    success = Abbreviations.TryGetValue(abbreviation, out offset);
    if (!success)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Unknown time zone abbreviation.", "input");
    }

    // apply the offset to the datetime, and return
    return new DateTimeOffset(dt, offset);
}
```

Now it will return the correct output:

```
string dtString = "Mar 21, 2015 10:15 AM CDT";
DateTimeOffset dto = ParseInput(dtString);
Console.WriteLine(dto);
```

[image: Output]

Also note that if you were really trying to cover [all legal US time zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_States#United_States_time_zones), you should also consider adding `HAST`, `HADT`, `CHST`, `SST`, and `AST` to the list.